# How to find IPMI devices?

Tags: dell-poweredge, windows-server-2003-r2, ipmi

I am trying to install Hardware Management as per instructions on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781099%28WS.10%29.aspx and am getting the error in step 4 "An IPMI device has been registered within the system BIOS..." etc.

I don't want to continue the install until I know what it's referring to - any ideas how I can find all IPMI devices?

Answer (score 1):

This is referring to 3rd party drivers like [this intel one](http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/kern/imbdrv130.zip). Unless you've actively sought out the driver and installed it, it's unlikely to be on there.

Incidentally you might need this hotfix to get ipmi working on 2003 r2:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912134

Answer (score 1):

You can use dell ipmitool for more details check this url.
http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/power/ps4q04-20040204-Murphy.pdf